# A method of calculation coordinates in order to implement it to a code language!

Tags: trigonometry, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems, systems-of-equations

lets say that we have three points A(xa,ya,za), B(xb,yb,zv), C(xc,yc,zc) with known coordinates in 3d space. Is there a method to calculate the coordinates (x,y,z) of another point D for which the following applies:

```
1) the angle ABD is equal to DBC and with known value lets say θ
2) The |BD| is also known lets say l.
```

I need a method that can easily imported to a program language such as fortran like a 3x3 system that can be easily solved calling a subroutine from the available library.

Two equations come to my mind so far:

the firsts has to do with the inner product of the vectors

```
AB*BD=|AB|.|BD|.COSΘ
CB*BD=|CB|.|BD|.COSΘ
```

and

```
sqrt((x-xb)^2+(y-yb)^2+(z-zb)^2)=l
```

but the system so far is not linear and it will be difficult to input to a code.

Comment: I assume this is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810397/algorithms-for-adding-hydrogens-on-a-molecule)? Anyway, I don't think you can avoid solving a quadratic equation here; the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) is your friend. Note that, as is typical for quadratic equations, your problem will have either two solutions (one on each side of the ABC plane) or no solutions at all, with a single solution only in the special case that ∠ABC = ∠ABD + ∠DBC.